# Matrix and derivations rules

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am studying control systems and I noticed that i had problems specially when it comes to matrix derivations .

I am looking for a memento to remember rules about this subject.
Does anyone have anything at hand?
Thank you

Comment: See http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf, http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf and http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/cas/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppF.d/IFEM.AppF.pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector calculus, linear algebra, and differential forms: a unified approach with {Maple 10 VP} by Hubbard and Hubbard is a very gentle, yet thorough introduction.